# What is completion callback function? Example in C or Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, c, callback

I'm curios especially about word "completion"
Example in C or Objective-C?

Comment: check the docs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in short:
the idea of a completion function is: do something and tell me once you  did it

e.g. from UIKit

`pushViewController:animated:completionHandler:` or `animate:completion:`

the idea of callbacks I : Do something and tell me if something happens (it is more general. a completion function is a kind of callback)

e.g. from Apples FileSystemEvents - FSEvents

`FSEventStreamCreate` takes a callback that is being called whenever a FS Event occurred

---

### thats the gist. for more: please refer to some docs

### also of course this is my personal view of things